# chrome extension hot-reloading issue based on react.js and typescript by webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, webpack-dev-server

everyone.
I am working on building chrome extension and I have some trouble in the webpack configuration.
Firstly I have consisted of webpack.config.js like this.

```
// webpack.config.js 

    devServer: {
        static: [{
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        }, ],
        hot: true,
        port: 3000,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
        },
        devMiddleware: {
            writeToDisk: true
        },
    }

// background.ts
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
  console.log('WebSocket connected');
});

socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  if (typeof event.data === 'string') {
    console.log(event.data)
    const { type, data } = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (type == 'Ok') {
      console.log('Received HMR signal. Reloading extension');
      chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
  }
});
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log('onclicked')
  if (tab && tab.id) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 'toggleSidebar' });
  } else {
    console.error('No active tab found');
  }
});
export { }
// this is manifest.json
"permissions": ["bookmarks", "storage", "identity", "runtime", "http://localhost:3000/*"],
```

If I run `webpack serve` cli, then i always get errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClF2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGapB.png)

When I change something, I will get this errors.
dev server make hot-reloading but chrome.runtime.reload() is not running.

I tried webpackconfig but I dont think webpack config is good.
Maybe it is from manifest.json, contentscript.js or background.js files.